# Close v-autocomplete after selection

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I use vuetify `v-autocomplete` and I want it to close the dropdown, after each selection or deselection. This is my code so far

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="ddselect"
  :items="dditems"
  @change="ddchange"
  tags
  ref="ddselectRef"
  multiple
  dense
  disable-lookup
  return-object
></v-autocomplete>
```

and then I watch the `v-model`, based on the example [here](https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/MQRjme?&editors=101)

```
ddselect: {
  handler: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.ddselectRef.menuIsActive = false;
    }, 50);
  },
  deep: true,
  immediate: true
}
```

But its not working.

I also tried with menu-props

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="ddselect"
  :items="dditems"
  @change="ddchange"
  tags
  ref="ddselectRef"
  multiple
  dense
  disable-lookup
  return-object
  :menu-props="{ closeOnClick:true }"
></v-autocomplete>
```

How can I do that?

vue 3.9.3 with vuetify 2.2.12

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the menu-props is the right approach, but you're looking for

```
:menu-props="{closeOnContentClick:true}"
```

Comment: or simply `menu-props="closeOnContentClick"`

Comment: still does not work,, when clicking outside the v-autocomplete, the selection doesn't close

Comment: works in Vuetify3